# How can I change the background color of Ttabitem of TTabcontrol in firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How can I change the background color of Ttabitem  of TTabcontrol in firemonkey ?

Comment: Please, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and make sure you understand each point. Then also [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially about how to ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the StyleBook for your TabItem and add a color layer (e.g. tabcolor rectangle) like this:

```
object TStyleContainer
  object TLayout
    StyleName = 'tabitemstylecolor'
    Position.X = 546.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 397.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 67.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 26.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    object TTabStyleObject
      StyleName = 'top'
      Align = Contents
      ClipChildren = True
      Locked = True
      SourceLookup = 'Windows 10 Desktopstyle.png'
      Size.Width = 67.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 26.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      ActiveTrigger = Selected
      ActiveLink = <
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Top = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 55.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 90.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 97.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 114.000000000000000000
        end>
      SourceLink = <
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Top = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 5.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 90.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 47.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 113.000000000000000000
        end>
      HotLink = <
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Top = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 105.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 90.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 147.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 113.000000000000000000
        end>
      ActiveHotLink = <
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Top = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 55.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 90.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 97.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 114.000000000000000000
        end>
      FocusedLink = <
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Top = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 5.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 90.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 47.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 113.000000000000000000
        end>
      ActiveFocusedLink = <
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Top = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 105.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 118.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 147.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 142.000000000000000000
        end>
      object TRectAnimation
        Duration = 0.000009999999747379
        PropertyName = 'Margins'
        StartValue.Left = -1.000000000000000000
        StartValue.Top = 2.000000000000000000
        StartValue.Right = -1.000000000000000000
        StopValue.Left = -1.000000000000000000
        StopValue.Right = -1.000000000000000000
        StopValue.Bottom = -2.000000000000000000
        Trigger = 'IsSelected=True'
        TriggerInverse = 'IsSelected=false'
      end
      object TGlyph
        StyleName = 'glyphstyle'
        Margins.Left = 4.000000000000000000
        Margins.Right = -4.000000000000000000
        Align = Left
        Size.Width = 16.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 16.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
      end
      object TColorAnimation
        StyleName = 'coloranimation1'
        Duration = 0.200000002980232200
        StartValue = xFF29F029
        StopValue = xFFEA1818
        Trigger = 'IsSelected=true'
        TriggerInverse = 'IsSelected=false'
      end
      object TRectangle
        StyleName = 'tabcolor'
        Align = Client
        Fill.Color = xFFE76565
        HitTest = False
        Size.Width = 67.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 26.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
      end
      object TTabStyleTextObject
        StyleName = 'text'
        Align = Client
        Locked = True
        Margins.Left = 8.000000000000000000
        Margins.Top = 4.000000000000000000
        Margins.Right = 8.000000000000000000
        Margins.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 51.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 18.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        TextSettings.WordWrap = False
        ShadowVisible = False
        ActiveTrigger = Selected
        ActiveColor = claBlack
        HotColor = claBlack
      end
    end
    object TLayout
      StyleName = 'bottom'
      Align = Contents
      ClipChildren = True
      Locked = True
      Size.Width = 67.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 26.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      object TRectAnimation
        Duration = 0.000009999999747379
        PropertyName = 'Margins'
        StartValue.Left = -1.000000000000000000
        StartValue.Right = -1.000000000000000000
        StartValue.Bottom = 2.000000000000000000
        StopValue.Left = -1.000000000000000000
        StopValue.Top = -2.000000000000000000
        StopValue.Right = -1.000000000000000000
        Trigger = 'IsSelected=True'
        TriggerInverse = 'IsSelected=false'
      end
      object TTabStyleObject
        Align = Contents
        Locked = True
        SourceLookup = 'Windows 10 Desktopstyle.png'
        RotationAngle = 180.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 67.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 26.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        ActiveTrigger = Selected
        ActiveLink = <
          item
            CapInsets.Left = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Top = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Right = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 55.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 90.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 97.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 114.000000000000000000
          end>
        SourceLink = <
          item
            CapInsets.Left = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Top = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Right = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 5.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 90.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 47.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 113.000000000000000000
          end>
        HotLink = <
          item
            CapInsets.Left = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Top = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Right = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 105.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 90.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 147.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 113.000000000000000000
          end>
        ActiveHotLink = <
          item
            CapInsets.Left = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Top = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Right = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 55.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 90.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 97.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 114.000000000000000000
          end>
        FocusedLink = <
          item
            CapInsets.Left = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Top = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Right = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 5.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 90.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 47.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 113.000000000000000000
          end>
        ActiveFocusedLink = <
          item
            CapInsets.Left = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Top = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Right = 4.000000000000000000
            CapInsets.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Left = 105.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Top = 118.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Right = 147.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 142.000000000000000000
          end>
      end
      object TGlyph
        StyleName = 'glyphstyle'
        Margins.Left = 4.000000000000000000
        Margins.Right = -4.000000000000000000
        Align = Left
        Size.Width = 16.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 16.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
      end
      object TTabStyleTextObject
        StyleName = 'text'
        Align = Client
        Locked = True
        Margins.Left = 8.000000000000000000
        Margins.Top = 4.000000000000000000
        Margins.Right = 8.000000000000000000
        Margins.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 51.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 18.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        TextSettings.WordWrap = False
        ShadowVisible = False
        ActiveTrigger = Selected
        ActiveColor = claBlack
        HotColor = claBlack
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which will result in:

[image]